# Status Code 403: SignatureDoesNotMatch when I am using Amazon SES

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I created a new Amazon account. Created SMTP Credentials and used AWS Java SDK to send emails. But it is failing with following error:

> Status Code: 403, AWS Service: AmazonSimpleEmailService, AWS Request
>   ID: xyz, AWS Error Code: SignatureDoesNotMatch, AWS Error Message: The
>   request signature we calculated does not match the signature you
>   provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult
>   the service documentation for details.

Comment: For me, it was a clock skew issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22460549/470749

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The keys to be provided to send Emails are not "SMTP Credentials" . The keys are instead Global access key which can be retrieved http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/ses/latest/GettingStartedGuide/GetAccessIDs.html.

Comment: I'll be darned, but this is quite true. You need to create a global access key for AWS to be able to access SES. Use the URL https://console.aws.amazon.com/iam/home?#security_credential Note that this provides keys with unlimited access to the AWS account. Don't see why the SES can't make do with a more limited set of credentials...

Comment: Best practice is create a IAM user and then, create an Access ID for that user. You can limit user permissions now. All this actions must be done in AIM control panel: https://console.aws.amazon.com/iam/home

Comment: The answer above is correct , worked for me. There is just one caution I had to take, somehow when you download the credentials via csv format, they do not work, so copy from the aws console itself rather than downloading csv and copying from there.

Answer (score 17):

SMTP Credentials are not valid for use with SES API (AWS Java SDK). SMTP credential are in fact different to the ones manually created for IAM users, even that this different is not visible anywhere on AWS Console. Take a look here to see differences: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/using-credentials.html

You don't actually need to create Global Access credentials (which could be a security leak), but you should create a new IAM user with the following security policy, and create new credentials for that user.

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement":[{
   "Effect":"Allow",
   "Action":["ses:SendEmail", "ses:SendRawEmail"],
   "Resource":"*"
   }
]
}
```

PS: Probably, you could just add new credentials to the SMTP IAM user already created for SES, but I haven't yet tested this.

Comment: The policy works fine, but I had to create another credential to use with it.

Comment: Necro this thread:  for some reason I couldn't just add the SES policy to my existing user that I was using for SMTP.  I had to create a new IAM user and attach it there.  So I did what Carlos did, too.