# Service: AmazonSQS; Status Code: 403; Error Code: SignatureDoesNotMatch; SQS

Tags: java, amazon-ec2, amazon-sqs, aws-java-sdk, aws-java-sdk-2.x

i am running my simple class on ec2 to create or send messages on SQS. But this giving me Service: AmazonSQS; Status Code: 403; Error Code: SignatureDoesNotMatch;

i'm attaching my code and the error below:-

```
private AWSSimpleQueueServiceUtil() {
    try {
        this.simpleQueue = "demo-Photo-Queue";
        //this.sqs = (AmazonSQS) AmazonSQSClientBuilder.standard().build();
        //this.sqs.setEndpoint("https://a4b.us-east-1.amazonaws.com");
        this.sqs = (AmazonSQS)  AmazonSQSClientBuilder.standard()
        .withRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1)
        .build();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("exception while creating awss3client : " + e);
    }
}

public static AWSSimpleQueueServiceUtil getInstance() {
    return awssqsUtil;
}

public AmazonSQS getAWSSQSClient() {
    return awssqsUtil.sqs;
}

public String getQueueName() {
    return awssqsUtil.simpleQueue;
}

/**
 * Creates a queue in your region and returns the url of the queue
 * 
 * @param queueName
 * @return
 */
public String createQueue(String queueName) {
    CreateQueueRequest createQueueRequest = new CreateQueueRequest(queueName);
    String queueUrl = this.sqs.createQueue(createQueueRequest).getQueueUrl();
    return queueUrl;
}

/**
 * returns the queueurl for for sqs queue if you pass in a name
 * 
 * @param queueName
 * @return
 */
public String getQueueUrl(String queueName) {
    GetQueueUrlRequest getQueueUrlRequest = new GetQueueUrlRequest(queueName);
    return this.sqs.getQueueUrl(getQueueUrlRequest).getQueueUrl();
}

/**
 * send a single message to your sqs queue
 * 
 * @param queueUrl
 * @param message
 */
public void sendMessageToQueue(String queueUrl, String message) {
    SendMessageResult messageResult = this.sqs.sendMessage(new SendMessageRequest(queueUrl, message));
    System.out.println(messageResult.toString());
    System.out.println("send successfully");
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    //String thePath = "https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/685308457175/demo-Photo-Queue";
    String queueName = "myFisrtQueue";
    queueName = URLEncoder.encode(queueName, "UTF-8");
    System.out.println(queueName);
    AWSSimpleQueueServiceUtil.getInstance().createQueue("queueName");

}
```

and following is the error I received :-

> (Service: AmazonSQS; Status Code: 403; Error Code: SignatureDoesNotMatch; Request ID: 20311998-3b24-5878-a1d6-4d5cdc182fa2)
>       at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1592)
>       at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1257)
>       at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1029)
>       at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:741)
>       at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:715)
>       at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:697)
>       at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:665)
>       at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:647)
>       at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:511)
>       at com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSClient.doInvoke(AmazonSQSClient.java:1740)
>       at com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSClient.invoke(AmazonSQSClient.java:1716)
>       at com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSClient.executeSendMessage(AmazonSQSClient.java:1503)
>       at com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSClient.sendMessage(AmazonSQSClient.java:1480)
>       at com.SQSDemojava.demo.AWSSimpleQueueServiceUtil.sendMessageToQueue(AWSSimpleQueueServiceUtil.java:87)
>       at com.SQSDemojava.demo.AWSSimpleQueueServiceUtil.main(AWSSimpleQueueServiceUtil.java:120)
>   myFisrtQueue

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14297000/750510) answer your question?